# Can't play .mp4 files embedded in html5 player in Firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox, lubuntu, flash, mp4

I have just installed Lubuntu 14.04.

I can run .mp4 video files directly with Firefox but if i put them into an HTML5 tag then I get error: 'video format or mime type is not supported'.

I have been searching for a solution to this for hours now, I've tried so much but to no avail.

I am using Firefox version 28.0.
OS: LUbuntu 14.04 and I have:

- Installed flashplugin-installer.
- Set media.gstreamer.enabled to false in about:config.
- Changed the .htaccess file to include:

  AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v f4v f4p
  AddType video/ogg ogv
  AddType video/webm webm
  AddType video/x-flv flv

And I have also done:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

According to: [10 Things To Do After Installing Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr To Get A Near Perfect Desktop](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html)

Then I installed Lubuntu extras, as is detailed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats), but its all to no avail and the error just persists.

Does anybody know how I can get to view HTML5 embedded .mp4 files in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved it was to go in Firefox’ URL bar and type `about:config`,
and there set `media.gstreamer.enabled` to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

To "fix" this, all you need is install the "gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg" package and its dependencies. If you've upgraded from an older Ubuntu version, this package might already be installed but if this is a fresh install, you can get the package from a PPA. Add the PPA and install it using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html

Comment: I did that but to no avail. I updated the answer now.